# Differentiation of a Complicated Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, statistical-inference

Let, $h$ is differentiable function. $\theta_1\in\mathbb{R}$, $\theta_2>0$ $$F(\theta_1,\theta_2) = \int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{y}n(n-1)\frac{(y-x)^{n-2}}{(2\theta_2)^n}h(x,y)dxdy$$

I need to find $\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial \theta_1\partial \theta_2}$. I know Leibniz Rule for these type of cases. Is there any easy way to derive this? Thanks.

Comment: Using Fubini's theorem, we can write the double integral as iterated integrals. Then,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial\theta_2}&=\frac{n(n-1)}{2^n}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_2}\left\{\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^y\,dx\right\}\left\{\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}\frac{(y-x)^{n-2}}{\theta_2^n}h(x,y)\,dy\right\}
\\&=\frac{n(n-1)}{2^n}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_2}\frac{(y-\theta_1+\theta_2)}{\theta_2^n}\left\{\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}(y-x)^{n-2}h(x,y)\,dy\right\}
\end{align}
Use the product rule for differentiation. Leibniz rule applies as usual.